# Using same references with different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button, android-drawable

I have some images in my App and want to use the same reference for multiple screens, is it possible to use the scale tag in xml to re-size the image and use it with different resolutions? when i tried it the picture disappeared!

For example i did this :

First of all i created new XML file add_more_items_scaled

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/add_more_items"
    android:scaleWidth="75%"
    android:scaleHeight="75%">


</scale>
```

then created another XML file add_more_items_button

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_more_items_scaled"
        android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_more_items_scaled"></item>
```

and when i set the background of the button @android:background:"@drawable/add_more_items_button" it gives me an empty button

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cant apply scale tag to the Image, as it purpose it to scale drawables not images.

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale) for it says:

```
A drawable defined in XML that changes the size of another drawable based on its current level.
```

**solution:**

You can put a weight on your button and instead of using `Button` you can use `ImageButton` and set its `scaleType` to `fitXY` to fill the bound of it.